# Error when I try to read a JSON file as Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load my JSON File as a pd data frame, however I am running into this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deivs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-9e0d5e746a54>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/deivs/PycharmProjects/COVID_API/Tests_on_covid_data.py', wdir='C:/Users/deivs/PycharmProjects/COVID_API')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/deivs/PycharmProjects/COVID_API/Tests_on_covid_data.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_json('C:/Users/deivs/OneDrive/Desktop/Covid_state_data.json')
  File "C:\Users\deivs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\deivs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 608, in read_json
    result = json_reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\deivs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 731, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\deivs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 753, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "C:\Users\deivs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 857, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "C:\Users\deivs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 1089, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

The code I am using is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_json('C:/Users/deivs/OneDrive/Desktop/Covid_state_data.json')
df.head()
```

and my json file is in proper form (I checked on JSONLINT)

```
[
    {

        "date": 20200402,
        "state": "AL",
        "positive": 1233,
        "negative": 7503,
        "pending": null,
        "hospitalizedCurrently": null,
        "hospitalizedCumulative": null,
        "inIcuCurrently": null,
        "inIcuCumulative": null,
        "onVentilatorCurrently": null,
        "onVentilatorCumulative": null,
        "recovered": null,
        "dataQualityGrade": "B",
        "lastUpdateEt": "4/2/2020 00:00",
        "hash": "3b7e06a8f363841e0c01239ec822fb61543caa33",
        "dateChecked": "2020-04-02T20:00:00Z",
        "death": 32,
        "hospitalized": null,
        "total": 8736,
        "totalTestResults": 8736,
        "posNeg": 8736,
        "fips": "01",
        "deathIncrease": 6,
        "hospitalizedIncrease": 0,
        "negativeIncrease": 806,
        "positiveIncrease": 156,
        "totalTestResultsIncrease": 962
    },...]
```

I am sorry for the length, but I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Just because your .json file is valid JSON data, doesn't mean it's all properly formatted in the specific way that Pandas expects. See if you can cut down the file until you have the minimal amount of data necessary to reproduce the issue, and show us what that looks like.

Comment: oh, so you're saying that the file might be too big?I'll do that rn @KarlKnechtel

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you give a small file that still causes the problem, then that is something we can look at and tell you what's wrong with it. There's no reason to show any more data than actually causes the problem, after all.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the same file that you are trying to read (assuming "},...]" indicates more valid records), it is working fine for me. This is what I did.

sample.json:

```
[
    {
        "date": 20200402,
        "state": "AL",
        "positive": 1233,
        "negative": 7503,
        "pending": null,
        "hospitalizedCurrently": null,
        "hospitalizedCumulative": null,
        "inIcuCurrently": null,
        "inIcuCumulative": null,
        "onVentilatorCurrently": null,
        "onVentilatorCumulative": null,
        "recovered": null,
        "dataQualityGrade": "B",
        "lastUpdateEt": "4/2/2020 00:00",
        "hash": "3b7e06a8f363841e0c01239ec822fb61543caa33",
        "dateChecked": "2020-04-02T20:00:00Z",
        "death": 32,
        "hospitalized": null,
        "total": 8736,
        "totalTestResults": 8736,
        "posNeg": 8736,
        "fips": "01",
        "deathIncrease": 6,
        "hospitalizedIncrease": 0,
        "negativeIncrease": 806,
        "positiveIncrease": 156,
        "totalTestResultsIncrease": 962
    }
]
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_json("sample.json").T

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                                                 0
dataQualityGrade                                                 B
date                                                      20200402
dateChecked                                   2020-04-02T20:00:00Z
death                                                           32
deathIncrease                                                    6
fips                                                             1
hash                      3b7e06a8f363841e0c01239ec822fb61543caa33
hospitalized                                                   NaN
hospitalizedCumulative                                         NaN
hospitalizedCurrently                                          NaN
hospitalizedIncrease                                             0
inIcuCumulative                                                NaN
inIcuCurrently                                                 NaN
lastUpdateEt                                        4/2/2020 00:00
negative                                                      7503
negativeIncrease                                               806
onVentilatorCumulative                                         NaN
onVentilatorCurrently                                          NaN
pending                                                        NaN
posNeg                                                        8736
positive                                                      1233
positiveIncrease                                               156
recovered                                                      NaN
state                                                           AL
total                                                         8736
totalTestResults                                              8736
totalTestResultsIncrease                                       962
```

Comment: that's so weird because i still get the error message!

Comment: Only thing is that I transposed the data using (.T) but that is more for aesthetics, the error still does not makes any sense.

Comment: Can you try adding lines=True -> pd.read_json('C:/Users/deivs/OneDrive/Desktop/Covid_state_data.json', lines=True)